# How can i remove .html in my URL

Tags: url, url-rewrite

In my site url display like **www.abcd.com/one.html**, How can i remove **.html** in my url.

> Note : Product Url Suffix & Category Url Suffix **EMPTY**

Still my url display .html, How can i remove

Comment: Did you try system -> configuration -> Search engine Optimization -> Product URL Suffix(remove) & Category URL Suffix(remove)

Comment: Bro, i mentioned above,  Product Url Suffix & Category Url Suffix EMPTY, still display like .html

Comment: ok please reindex it

Comment: i did, bro but no improvement

Comment: Remove var folder from root

Comment: please check once reindex is done successfully or not it issue because of reindex only

Comment: This is my ststus

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Atmhhbj.png

Answer (score 1):

In backend go to

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog
```

Go To
**Search Engine Optimization tab**

Set

> Category URL Suffix to null , Product URL Suffix to null

Run command,

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Clear browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow my suggestions for you.

run below commands

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Delete **var** folder

Delete your **browser cache**.

I hope it will work for you.